# call mapfragment from activity

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have defined a `GoogleMap` as:

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and

**fragment.java**

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment implements onMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public static SecondFragment newInstance() {
        SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, null, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

and my main **activity** is:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        //mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        //mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        //mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        //Get Location Permission
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                    {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);

        }

        // Tab to get Date TODO: Expand fo both Location and Date
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showDateDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    public void showDateDialog() {
        DialogFragment CalFragment = new CalFragment();
        CalFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch (pos) {

                case 0:
                    return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
                case 1:
                    return SecondFragment.newInstance();
                case 2:
                    return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
                case 3:
                    return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 2");
                case 4:
                    return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 3");
                default:
                    return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

which is saying that the `mMap` symbol cannot be resolved.
How should I call the map from the activity? What I am going wrong here?

I am using `android-support-v4`.

Comment: didn't understand why you are passing GoogleMap object to the fragment? you can simply call new SecondFragment() ??

Comment: hi Ankit, because i am very new to java and don't understand its philosophy well. May i kindly request you to show me how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not instantiate any Fragment like you need. bcoz parameterized constructor can not be created with Fragment.

Correct your code with following :

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    case 1:
      return new SecondFragment.newInstance(); // replace with this line
    break;
}
```

Comment: Ankit, thanks a lot. Now its working in the sense that there is no error, but the fragment is still not visible (in my pager, it goes from 2nd to third directly)

Comment: did you add break statement with switch case?

Comment: did it. Thanks. But can you kindly tell me why the map is not visible?

Comment: can you show me the code of your activity? please update the question with activity's code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164973/discussion-between-ankit-mehta-and-barud).

Comment: Please come to the chat

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't create the Fragment with:

```
return SecondFragment(GoogleMap mMap);
```

Because you only have a default constructor on your SecondFragment which is:

```
public SecondFragment();
```

or static method:

```
public static SecondFragment newInstance();
```

to create the Fragment.

And you also didn't create the Fragment with new keyword. Each object in Java need to be created with `new`. Except if your `SecondFragment(GoogleMap mMap);` is a method.

So, you need to create the Fragment with:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    case 1:
       return new SecondFragment.newInstance();
       // or 
       // return new SecondFragment();
```

To access the `private GoogleMap mMap;` variable, you can use a getter in your Fragment like this:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment implements onMapReadyCallback {
  private GoogleMap mMap;

  public GoogleMap getMap() {
    return mMap;
  }
  ...
}
```